# Django/postgres transaction isolation level setting ignored

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an issue setting transaction isolation level. I want the most strict serializable, while the default is read committed.

I am using:

```
Django==1.10.6
psycopg2==2.5.1
```

Running on heroku.

Based on the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#isolation-level

I have the following settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
        'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
    }
}

if on_heroku:
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Here's the view code:

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@transaction.atomic
@login_required()
def api_test_add_one(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SHOW default_transaction_isolation')

    logger.info("aa: " + str(cursor.fetchone()))

    return HttpResponse("{}", content_type="application/json")
```

The output is:

```
aa: (u'read committed',)
```

I have run different tests simultaneously accessing the same endpoint, incrementing an integer in DB and confirmed that transactions were not isolated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OPTIONS belongs *inside* the database's settings, e.g.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgres',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
        },
    },
}
```

In your case, you replace `DATABASES['default']`, so your `OPTIONS` set there would be lost:

```
if on_heroku:
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Instead, you can set `OPTIONS` after setting `DATABASES['default']`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

if on_heroku:
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
    DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
        'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
    }
```

Comment: That was it, I wish I asked sooner!